# Laravel query on foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have the following structure. While user registers, he selects a country. he creates a post. I want to search all posts of a particular country that has search keyword. Search keyword could be the title, model, price anything. It works fine.

However, I also want to be able to search make names. But unlike other fields, make name is not directly saved in my table, it saves an ID for a make name to be picked from a different table.

How can I search based on make name as well?

Model - POsts relationship. Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $dates = ['status_change'];

    public function make_rel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class, 'make_id' ,'id','make_logo');
    }

}
```

So basically I create a post. During creation, I can select a make. 
Post table saves mak id. Make is saved in a different table as Id, make_name.

Make Table:
[image: Make Table]

Post Table:

[image: Post Table]

Now I want to do a query on posts table based on make:

```
$posts = Country::where('country_name', $request->input('country'))->first()->posts()->orderBy('status_change','DESC')
        ->where('status','Published')
        ->where(function($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
            $query->orWhere('model','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
            $query->orWhere('notes','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
            $query->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
        })
        ->paginate(25);
        }
```

Comment: What is the name of the make table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereHas` for this. In your `->where(function($query) use ($search){` block:

```
->orWhereHas('make_rel', function($query) use($search) {
    $query->where('make_name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
}
```